# Multiple IR Key Press Events

Tags: c, serial-port, device-driver, linux-device-driver, infrared

I'm currently working on an IR key handler for a box running on linux kernel 2.6.15. I'm fetching IR key events from tts/1. The issue I'm facing is that for a single key press on the remote results in 2-3 key press events.

What I'mm doing is that I'm reading from the file descriptor of tts/1 using read(). What I have seen is that for a single key press I got the same key code twice(sometime thrice). I think that this is not a hardware issue. I' using standard UART code.

Anybody has any idea ?

Comment: Do you know if there's a key-repeat threshold (and interval)?

Comment: I think your handler should use the delay/repeat rate configured by `kbdrate` (ioctl `KDKBDREP` if I'm not mistaken. Check `<linux/kd.h>`).

Answer (score 0):

You could do like most devices and just add a minimum delay between repeated keystrokes. I did that for a custom key input device on windows and it worked really well. It's the same as your keyboard. When you hold down a key, it pauses after the first reaction. Later repeats are faster but still have built in minimum delays.
(not sure if I'm phrasing it right but it worked great for me. I was writing a program to generate keystrokes as a reaction to repeating input signals.)

Comment: I'm doing that but on higher speeds once in a while I could see multiple key events for a single key press. I'm taking the delay time as 120 msecs. I can't take it more then that otherwise if I press keys fast it get skipped.